# Managing advertising code snippets

Tags: wp-admin, javascript

I'm looking for a solution to manage a mix of advertising code snippets.

Lets say you have three advertising contracts.

```
adService1, adService2, adService3
```

each of them will have some code in the site  section

```
adService1.head
adService2.head
adService3.head
```

then you have different advertising zones (zoneA, zoneB, zoneC)

```
<div id="adZoneA">
  <!--
    echo *.zoneA
    // displaying any adService having a code for zoneA
  -->
</div>

<div id="adZoneB">
  <!--
    echo *.zoneB
    // displaying any adService having a code for zoneB
  -->
</div>
<!-- etc... -->
```

having to manage this by hand would soon become difficult to maintain, so I'm looking into what king of tools I could base myself on.
Most of what I've found as plugins tries to be more of a advertising management tool (ad serving system a bit like revive-adserver.com) that tries to manage and count views and clicks.

As this is for a heavy traffic website, I can not afford to have a complex system behind this and all I need is to spit out some text (javascript code) specific to keys that I can query with a wildecard/grouping method.

Thanks for pointing me out into a direction to a simple and robust solution.

Comment: Check out [shortcodes UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ui/) - you can create placeholders like `[adservice-1]` to use anywhere in your content, and configure all the HTML/CSS/JS in one place

Comment: I'm now looking into this.  I was looking into 'option tree' hoping there would be a way to query option ids using wildcards

Comment: Google Tag Manager is awesome for this kind of problem.